# Does VERY little time mean no time at all?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

The sentence below is from my book. I know that "little" means a small amount. Does "**very** little" mean having no time at all or still having a very small amount of time?

> Many people work long hours, leaving **very little** time for leisure
> activities.

A native speaker paraphrased the sentence to: "many people have experienced a loss of leisure time due to having to work long hours." That's why I thought "very little" might mean zero.

Comment: I've answered, but could you expalin more why you suppose that "very little" could mean "none".  Is it the context of the sentence?

Comment: Thanks, @JamesK. A native speaker paraphrased the sentence to: many people have experienced **a loss** of leisure time due to having to work long hours. That's why I thought "very little" might mean zero.

Comment: very little cannot mean none or no [something].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has no special meaning.  "very little time" means "a small but non-zero amount of time"

Similarly if you lose leisure time, it doesn't imply that you lose it all.  You can experience a loss of leisure time, but still have a little left.

But the paraphrase has a slightly different meaning. The paraphrase means "they have less leisure time than they had before" and the original means "now they have very little leisure time"

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So, if I say I experienced a loss of money, that means I lost almost all my money but still have a little left? I don't even need to modify "loss". I mean, I don't need to say something like "a great loss"?

Comment: @Learner110 - If you have a loss of money (with no other words) you lose an unspecified sum of money. You can add some words to make it clearer, e.g. I had a large loss of money, I had a small loss of money.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, thank you very much for your comments. What about the use of "loss" in my original question? If I want to use "loss" to say very little leisure time, then I need words like "great" and say "experienced a great loss of leisure time"?

Comment: @Learner110 I've edited.